# Is dart really 100% pure object oriented programming language

Tags: dart, object

While learning the basics of `dart`, it mentions that `dart` is a 100% pure object oriented programming language. Event primitive types, like int and double, are objects and are passed as a reference and not a value.

```dart
 void main() {
  double number = 44;
  print('before $number');
  changeNumber(number); // with this it does not print 45
  // number++; with this it does print 45;
  print('after $number');
}

void changeNumber(double number) => number++;
```

Output: 
before 45 
after 44

Why does the other function not mutate it when passed?. I know `dart` passed a numeric value, but why it does it do it that way?

Comment: Just because everything is an object does not mean everything is mutable. `++` will create a new object

Comment: Take claims like "pure object-oriented language" with a grain of salt (and strictly speaking, Dart doesn't make that claim). Almost no languages are purely object-oriented, and certainly no modern mainstream languages are. Many of them are multi-paradigm languages that simply include all of the _common_ object-oriented concepts like class-based design and inheritence/polymorphism. See languages like [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) for what a "pure object-oriented language" actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

> I am expecting that people explain me if int is an object why other function cannot mutate it when passed, i know dart passed numeric by value by it does that way.

As mousetail also mention in their comment, just because something is an object, it does not mean that the state of the object is mutable. Lot of classes in Dart are designed to make immutable objects where any kind of mutation would result in another object instance.

E.g. `int`, `double` and `String` are all types of classes where the objects of those classes are immutable.

In your example, the `number++` operation means `number = number + 1`. The `+` operator on `number` (`double`) are here defined to take the `1`, and return a new `double` object where we have the result of adding `1` to `number`.

Since we are not manipulating the `number` object itself, any reference to this object will still observe the original value of `number`.

We do, however, reassign the new `double` instance to the variable `number`. This is why this is working inside `main` since the variable is a local variable and you are allowed to change what value it is referencing to.

But a parameter to a function are sent as a copy of a reference. So if we manipulate the inner state of the object, sent to the function, then these changes would be visible for the caller of the function. But if we change the reference/parameter to point to some other object, then this change would not be visible for the caller.

And since `double` is an immutable object, we are guarantee that any change of this object would result in another object instance and therefore we need to change the reference to this new object for the change to be observed. And since a argument to a function is a copy of a reference, then any change to this copy-reference cannot be observed outside of the function itself.

Comment: in main function `number++` changes original number to be incremented by 1 but in `changeNumber` function it does not go that way

Comment: @ManishRajYadav Fair point. I have given a second attempt to try explain what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> even primitive types like int,double are objects and are passed as reference not value.

Dart doesn't really have references (or pointers) so this sentence is not very helpful in understanding what's going on.

A function parameter can be thought of as a local variable to which the caller's arguments are assigned. The new variable gets "the same" value as the original variable (but it's not a reference in the sense you have in C - you can't pass the reference around and let others change what it points to).

In your example, when you call `changeNumber(number)`, you could replace that with this:

```
  double number = 44;
  print('before $number');

  // changeNumber scope
  {
      var $number = number;
      // body of changeNumber function
      $number++;
  }
  
  // number++; with this it does print 45;
  print('after $number');
```

This is called "inlining" and the compiler may actually do that automatically. Anyway, you've basically changed the value held by the `$number` variable, not the original `number` as that is not accessible within the scope of the called function (it is in the example above, but the compiler would've prevented you from using it in reality).

Hopefully, you understand that `number++` does not alter the "interior" of the `number` variable, it just returns a new number which is then assigned to the same variable.... in other words, this is what's actually happening:

```
number = number + 1;
```

Object-orientation has nothing to do with any of this, as others have pointed out, as in OOP an Object is allowed to be completely immutable, and numbers in Dart are immutable. You can easily create immutable Objects yourself in Dart 3, for example:

```
final class ComplexNumber {
  final double real;
  final double imaginary;
  const ComplexNumber(this.real, this.imaginary);
  @override
  String toString() => 'Complex($real, $imaginary)';
}
```

You can add methods for adding a `ComplexNumber` to another, but then you need to return a new one instead of changing the current one to keep it immutable:

```
final class ComplexNumber {
  final double real;
  final double imaginary;
  const ComplexNumber(this.real, this.imaginary);
  @override
  String toString() => 'Complex($real, $imaginary)';
  operator +(ComplexNumber other) =>
      ComplexNumber(real + other.real, imaginary + other.imaginary);
}

main() {
  print(ComplexNumber(1.0, 2.4) + ComplexNumber(2.0, 3.5));
}
```

You could have made `ComplexNumber` mutable, but even in modern OOP, it's generally preferred to make Objects immutable because that aids the ability to reason about a program immensely (at the possible cost of performance, as it may be much more efficient to change something than to allocate new objects on every change).